# parsing input and output filename as argument from command line

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I am new with c++ and in a project i need to use command line argument.
I read about command line arguments i.e including

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
}
```

but i have a problem declaring my filename in the source file.

i declared my input and output filename in the source file(file_process.cpp) as

```
const char iFilename[] ;
const char oFilename[] ;
```

defined the function(which uses the input file - iFilename and process the output in the oFilename) as

```
void file_process::process(iFilename[], oFilename[])
{
body...
}
```

and in the main method as :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    iFilename[] = argv[1];
    oFilename[] = argv[2];
    file_process::process(iFilename[], oFilename[]);

}
```

earlier i hardcoded the filename to test my program without arguments in the main method and declaring the variable in the source file(file_process.cpp)as:

```
const char iFilename[] = "input_file.pdf";
const char oFilename[]  = "output_file.txt";
```

and its working fine but when I am trying to take the arguments from the command line as stated above and I am not able to compile it.

Is it the right way of doing it in c++ ? I work with c# and there simply declaring in the source file like:

```
string iFilename = args[0];
string oFilename = args[1];
```

works.
I

Comment: In C++ you would do nearly the same as in C#, that is: `std::string  iFilename = argv[1]`, and then pass the variable as a C++-string to the function or as a C-string using std::string::c_str().

Comment: You are not able to compile it, because...?

Comment: `file_process::process` will need a type of parameter, not just a name. Don't forget arg[0] is the exe name. Don't forget `const` where needed. Or use a `std::string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    assert(argc >= 3);
    const std::string iFilename = argv[1];
    const std::string oFilename = argv[2];
    file_process::process(iFilename, oFilename);
}
```

And you `file_process::process` could be:

```
void file_process::process(const std::string& iFilename, const std::string& oFilename)
{
    body...
}
```

Comment: I did as you said 
But when I am editing my file_process::process as

void file_process::process(const std::char& iFilename[], const std::string& oFilename[]);

the compiler shows an error in the above line as " error: expected ‘)’ " , though I can't see any need for this closing paranthesis.
Another error in the above line is "expected initializer"
I initialized the iFilename and oFilename as global const as:
const char iFilename[100];
const char oFilename[100];

Comment: Either go for C-strings or C++-strings you should not mixed, that is just weird. And it is not std::string[] that is an array of std::string...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out it was a typo.
I fixed the code now, your second point regarding the array of std::string was helpful indeed.
Now I am having the problem at runtime stating "int main(int, char**): Assertion 'argc>=3' failed."

Comment: The assert is there to ensure you remember to actually provide command-line arguments, if you don't it will assert.

Comment: I have another problem in the project now.
I am using netbeans and I didn't add arguments in the project properties. Now the project is compiling but at the run time it states /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
I googled but couldn't find a concrete answer. Any idea what is the problem ?

Comment: Please add a new question with a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But you should also get familiar with a debugger such as GDB.